# Android java Random image

Tags: java, android

How can i do this

Basically:

There is 2 images and i want them to be falling down a line and random of the 2 images will pop up

So like

Girl
Girl
Boy
Girl
Boy

And they will just falling down a straight line? how can i do this ill get more info if needed

Answer (score 1):

I would add a reference to your images in an ArrayList and generate a random number within 0 and the length of your list. Then display the images based on the random numbers you generate. As far as falling down the line...im not sure what that means.

Comment: like they just move in a straight line going down

Answer (score 0):

Use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-summary.html to translate the image randomly generated, or use a canvas and Translate the bitmap : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap, android.graphics.Rect, android.graphics.RectF, android.graphics.Paint)